Ngrok - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I am using Ngrok to expose my local IIS to the internet.
After setting up Ngrok to map to my IIS website, when I try and browse the ngrok URL.
I see in the browser an error message
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
and the website dosn't load.
I have used Ngrok many times with no issues, but now I am over seas using a hotel wifi connection, could this be the reason? - I don't think it is.
When I remove the bindding in IIS, and then visit the ngrok URL, I see the default IIS screen, so that means it is reaching my local machine.
So why am I getting this error?

Same here! Have you solved?
